# I have same problem of directory, i tried to change the directory of session from R studio

Tags: directory, read.csv

[error showing in the mardown file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlOVb.png)

[error showing in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQg4z.png)

Itry try to read this csv file but still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory seems to already be the `.../data` directory, so looking for a file will only lead you to search in the `.../data/data` directory. Is that what you are looking for? If not, try removing the `data/` in your file path when reading, it may fix your problem.

Comment: please see the guidance in [answer] on answering problematic questions.